# Keras data generators for image inpainting using autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, data-generation, image-enhancement

I am trying to train an autoencoder for image inpainting where the input images are the corrupted ones, and the output images are the ground truth.

The dataset used is organized as:

```
/Dataset
    /corrupted
         img1.jpg
         img2.jpg
            .
            .
    /groundTruth
         img1.jpg
         img2.jpg
            .
            .
```

The number of images used is relatively large. How can I feed the data to the model using Keras image data generators? I checked flow_from_directory method but couldn't find a proper class_mode to use (each image in the 'corrupted' folder maps to the one with the same name in 'groundTruth' folder)

Answer (score 0):

If there no pre-built image data generator that provides the functionality you require, you can create your own **custom data generator**.

To do so, you must create your new data generator class by subclassing `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`. You are required to implement the `__getitem__` and the `__len__` methods in the your new class. `__len__` must return the number of batches in your dataset, while `__getitem__` must return the elements in a single batch as a tuple.

You can read the official docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras). Below is a code example:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import math

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

Hope the answer was helpful!